# Lombok Setter Compilation Error - "getApiCti() method not found" in Spring Boot 3.2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, migration, lombok

Problem:

I'm encountering a compilation error while using Lombok annotations in my Spring Boot 3.2.2 project. The error occurs when accessing the setter for the getApiCti() method. The compiler complains that the symbol "getApiCti()" is not found.

Environment:

Spring Boot 3.2.2
Lombok 1.18.30
IDE: Intellij
Expected Behavior:

The Lombok setter should be able to access and modify the getApiCti() method.

Actual Behavior:

Compilation fails with the error "getApiCti() method not found".

Things I've Tried:

Verified Lombok dependency inclusion and scope in pom.xml.
Checked import statements and class visibility.

context : i did migrate my app from spring boot 2.6.2 to 3.2.2  and i can't use lombok propelry since
i can't run my app it returns this error
i tried to verify my pom.xml but always getting same error
i cleared cache as well and tried to exclude plugin in my pom.xml but still encountering same problem

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getApiCti()
  location: variable applicationProperties of type com.sncf.mycot.config.ApplicationProperties
```

even when i do mvn clean install
i'm using jdk 17

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\Users\Downloads\apache-maven-3.9.6-bin\apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 17.0.10, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.10
```

that's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.sncf.mycot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Mycot</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Dependency versions -->
        <jhipster.version>1.3.1</jhipster.version>
        <jhipster-dependencies.version>2.1.1</jhipster-dependencies.version>
        <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.2</spring-boot.version>
        <commons-lang.version>3.8.1</commons-lang.version>
        <org-jacoco.version>0.8.8</org-jacoco.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.9.1</jsonwebtoken.version>
        <liquibase-slf4j.version>2.0.0</liquibase-slf4j.version>

        <!-- Sonar -->
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
            ${project.basedir}/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
        </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster</artifactId>
            <version>${jhipster.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Token JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
        <!-- Openapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Base de données -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

            <!-- <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                     <excludes>
                         <exclude>
                             <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                             <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                         </exclude>
                     </excludes>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <!-- For JPA static metamodel generation -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org-jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>5.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is my ApplicationProperties class

```
package com.sncf.mycot.config;

import com.sncf.mycot.domain.ApiCti;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Properties specific to JHipster.
 * <p>
 * Properties are configured in the application.yml file.
 */
@ConfigurationProperties()
@Configuration
@Data
public class ApplicationProperties {

    String apiKey;
    Proxy proxy;
    String version;
    String environnement;
    @Value("${application.security.jwt-token}")
    private String jwtToken;
    @Value("${sso.api.enabled}")
    private boolean enabled;

    private ApiCti apiCti;
    private String idClient;

    public ApplicationProperties(@Value("${application.api-key}") String apiKey,
                                 @Value("${application.proxy.url}") String proxyUrl,
                                 @Value("${application.proxy.port}") String proxyPort,
                                 @Value("${application.version}") String version,
                                 @Value("${application.env}") String environnement,
                                 @Value("${application.api_cti.url}") String apiCtiUrl,
                                 @Value("${application.api_cti.api_key}") String apiCtiKey,
                                 @Value("${application.id_client}") String idClient) {

        this.apiKey = apiKey;

        this.proxy = new Proxy();
        this.proxy.url = proxyUrl;
        this.proxy.port = proxyPort;

        this.version = version;
        this.environnement = environnement;
        this.apiCti = new ApiCti();
        this.apiCti.setUrl(apiCtiUrl);
        this.apiCti.setApiKey(apiCtiKey);
        this.idClient = idClient;
    }

    public String getIdClient() {
        return idClient;
    }

    public void setIdClient(String idClient) {
        this.idClient = idClient;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getEnvironnement() {
        return environnement;
    }

    public void setEnvironnement(String environnement) {
        this.environnement = environnement;
    }

    public String getJwtToken() {
        return jwtToken;
    }

    public void setJwtToken(String jwtToken) {
        this.jwtToken = jwtToken;
    }

    public Proxy getProxy() {
        return proxy;
    }

    public void setProxy(Proxy proxy) {
        this.proxy = proxy;
    }



    public void setApiCti(ApiCti apiCti) {
        this.apiCti = apiCti;
    }

    public static class Proxy {
        public String url;
        public String port;
    }
}
```

and this where i'm using the getter

````
package com.sncf.mycot.http;


import com.sncf.mycot.config.ApplicationProperties;
import com.sncf.mycot.service.dto.CtiDto;
import com.sncf.mycot.service.dto.CtiTranslateDto;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.http.client.JdkClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClient;


@Component
public class CtiRestClient {
    private final RestClient restClient;
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    public CtiRestClient(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, RestClient.Builder builder, ClientHttpRequestInterceptor M2MRestClientInterceptor) {
        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
        this.restClient = builder
                .baseUrl(applicationProperties.getApiCti().getUrl())
                .defaultHeader("X-API-Key", applicationProperties.getApiCti().getApiKey())
                .requestFactory(new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory())
                .requestInterceptor(M2MRestClientInterceptor)
                .build();
    }

    public CtiDto[] getCtis() {
        System.out.printf("this is a ctis calling method");
        return this.restClient.get()
                .uri("/cti").retrieve().body(CtiDto[].class);
    }

    public CtiDto getCti(Long uuid) {
        return this.restClient.get().uri("/cti/" + uuid).retrieve().body(CtiDto.class);
    }

    public CtiTranslateDto getCtiTranslate(Long uuid) {
        return this.restClient.get().uri("/cti_translate/" + uuid).retrieve().body(CtiTranslateDto.class);
    }

    public RestClient getRestClient() {
        return this.restClient;
    }

    public ApplicationProperties getApplicationProperties() {
        return this.applicationProperties;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof CtiRestClient)) return false;
        final CtiRestClient other = (CtiRestClient) o;
        if (!other.canEqual((Object) this)) return false;
        final Object this$restClient = this.getRestClient();
        final Object other$restClient = other.getRestClient();
        if (this$restClient == null ? other$restClient != null : !this$restClient.equals(other$restClient))
            return false;
        final Object this$applicationProperties = this.getApplicationProperties();
        final Object other$applicationProperties = other.getApplicationProperties();
        if (this$applicationProperties == null ? other$applicationProperties != null : !this$applicationProperties.equals(other$applicationProperties))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
        return other instanceof CtiRestClient;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 59;
        int result = 1;
        final Object $restClient = this.getRestClient();
        result = result * PRIME + ($restClient == null ? 43 : $restClient.hashCode());
        final Object $applicationProperties = this.getApplicationProperties();
        result = result * PRIME + ($applicationProperties == null ? 43 : $applicationProperties.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "CtiRestClient(restClient=" + this.getRestClient() + ", applicationProperties=" + this.getApplicationProperties() + ")";
    }








/*



    public DetailAbonnementDTO[] getAbonnements() {
        return this.restClient.get().uri("/clients/" + this.applicationProperties.getIdClient()).retrieve().body(DetailAbonnementDTO[].class);
    }

    public DetailAbonnementDTO getAbonnement(UUID uuid) {
        return this.restClient.get().uri("/" + uuid).retrieve().body(DetailAbonnementDTO.class);
    }


*/
}```
````

Comment: You are using several outdated dependencies like jhipster (is already end of life? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster) which is also using an old spring boot version (2.2.4.Final)  etc. The property does not have a getter  `getApiCti()` ...

Comment: because i had to do the migration and i didn't know if i should remove the jhipster dependecies , also i didn't add a getter for the property because i wanted to directly use lombok , but lombok not working as expected while compiliation

Comment: Your pom file contains this note: _The spring-boot version should match the one managed by `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version}`_. Your jhipster-dependencies.version is 2.1.1 which defines a spring-boot.version of 2.0.8 which **doesn't** match your spring-boot.version. You should first fix this (probably by updating your jhipster versions) before searching any further.

Comment: “I had to do the migration” - so this is a work assignment which may require more experience than you have. Do you have senior developers you can consult ?